# how to get multiple column data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file. the format of file is below:

```
var data={"name":[[1,"kate"],[2,"david"]], "age":[[1,34],[2,25]],"sex":[[1,"female"],[2,"male"]]};
```

how to read the data format like this. 
if i directly use

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

can it recognize the colume name like "name" or "age". The data file is big, how to know how many entries in this data. 
I want to get the name value is "kate" and id is "1" and age is 34 and sex is "female". 
in the html it should show:

```
id  name age sex
1   kate  34  female
2   david 25  male
```

how to do parse json file to get the data

Comment: yes we can do it.. what do you want..?

Comment: obj.name[0] => [1,"kate"]

Comment: I want to get the name value is "kate" and id is "1" and age is 34 and sex is "female".

Comment: add the format you want in the question

Comment: I already add the format I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the table you want like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < data['name'].length; i++) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr/>')
    .append('<td>' + data['name'][i][0] + '</td><td>' + data['name'][i][1] + '</td><td>' + data['age'][i][1] + '</td><td>' + data['sex'][i][1]);
}
```

It will output

```
ID  Name    Age Sex
1   kate    34  male
2   david   25  female
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADLBM/)**

Answer (score 2):

Small Illustration Make a table

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/4jV95/1/)

```
var data = {"name":[[1,"kate"],[2,"david"]], "age":[[1,34],[2,25]],"sex":[[1,"male"],[2,"female"]]};
var nameFields = data.name;
var age = data.age;
var sex = data.sex;
var html = "";
for(var v in nameFields){
    html += "<tr><td>"+nameFields[v][0] +"</td><td>"+  nameFields[v][1] + "</td><td>"+ age[v][1] +"</td><td> " + sex[v][1] +"</td></tr>";
}  
$("#tblBody").html(html);
```

Comment: If I get the code from jsfiddle to html local file. Why it doesn't show the data result.